# Cannot use object of type Album\Model\Album as array - ZF2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to follow the albums list tutorial from Zend's official website but I'm stuck at an error I can't find the solution. I'm copying the code from the website yet it shows the error I wrote in the title.

The code in that class is in the file `Album.php`:

```
 public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
     $this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
     $this->artist = (isset($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : null;
     $this->title = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
 }
```

And it happens when I try to edit an album I have, accessing the file `edit.phtml`:

```
 <?php
 $title = 'Edit album';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

 <?php
 $form = $this->form;
 $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
     'album',
      array(
         'action' => 'edit',
         'id'     => $this->id,
      )
 ));
 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('artist'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
 ?>
```

I have no idea where else the error could be. I'm totally new at Zend. I would really appreciate if you could check what I've done so far in my [github](https://github.com/mfgabriel92/zendframework2-album-example).

The complete error message is:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Album\Model\Album as array in /var/www/html/zf/module/Album/src/Album/Model/Album.php on line 17
```

Thank you.

Comment: It showed me the columns of the table and their datas. Didn't understand what could it actually help me.

Comment: it must tell you what **exactly** you're passing. Guessing or assuming is never a win-strategy for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. It happens that I've copied the `addAction()` method and I had to delete two lines to make `editAction()` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind the object to your form:
`$form->bind($album);`

Comment: I already have put it in the code when I was copying from the website. It doesn't make any sense.